# How can I filter this table?

Tags: php, mysql

what should I add in this sql?
In my system I have *foreign Key*,`ID_Number`.I want that only one `ID_Number` must be shown in all `ID_Numbers` that having the same `ID_Number`.and choose all Bill.Arrears125 that not having 0 or Bill.Arrears521 not having 0 and Bill.Pay_Date must be on latest.

I need only to show all `ID_Number` where Arrears125 and Arrears521 are not equal to 0 and `Pay_Date` is newest

```
 __________________________________________________________
|  ID   | Arrears125 | Arrears521|  Pay_Date  |  ID_Number |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |      0     |     0     |  12-01-01  |      1     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|   2   |      0     |     0     |  12-01-02  |      1     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|   3   |      25    |     25    |  12-01-03  |      1     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|   4   |      0     |     0     |  12-01-01  |      2     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|   5   |      0     |     0     |  12-01-02  |      2     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|   6   |      0     |     0     |  12-01-01  |      3     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|   7   |      25    |     25    |  12-01-02  |      3     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

views only ID 3 and ID 7

```
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT
                        Bill.*,users.* from Bill,users
                    WHERE
                        users.ID_Number=Bill.ID_Number
                    AND
                        (Bill.Arrears125!=0 OR Bill.Arrears521!=0)
                    GROUP BY
                        Bill.ID_Number")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You can start by adding the `FROM <table>` part.. ;)

Comment: What does your query do (not do) that you expect it to not do (do)?

Comment: it must view only one ID_Number if the Bill.Arrears is true

Answer (score 0):

```
select str_to_date(Pay_Date,"%Y-%m-%d") as date_temp, ID_number from Bill where Appears125 != 0 and Appears521 != order by date_temp desc
```